# write outputs from a script run into singularity

Tags: singularity-container

I can't get the output of a script run through singularity.

I have a python script, at the end of which the output is saved with:

```
...
with open('saveOut.pkl','wb') as myFile:
    pickle.dump(myTable,myFile)
```

I want to run this script with singularity on a distant machine. Since I am learning singularity, I made a 'sand box' debian image (not compiled into a single 'img' file yet) in the directory `/tmp/debian`; in this image I copied the python script `test.py` in `/usr/src` and I run it with the command:

```
sudo singularity exec /tmp/debian python3.5 /usr/src/test.py
```

The problem:

It works well as long as I have only displayed results. with the pickle example described above, I don't get any `saveOut.pkl` file anywhere: this file is just not written anywhere but I don't see any message. I tried to write an explicit path in the python script. For instance `/usr/src/saveOut.pkl`, but this is the same.

How could I write a result ?

> What was your expected result i.e. in which directory did you expect
>   to find the output file?

I expect a file `saveOutput.pkl` anywhere, in the container or not, I don't care the location. Currently I don't get it at all: neither in the container's current directory, nor in the container's `/usr/src/`, nor on the host, nor anywhere.

> Did you look for it on the host or in the container?

both, I don't see it anywhere

Comment: What was your expected result i.e. in which directory did you expect to find the output file? Did you look for it on the host or in the container? Per default, Singularity will only share your home folder on the host with the container.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that your python script is writing the pickle file to its current location (/usr/src/ in the container). Then, since the output from your script is not persistent (due to the sandbox not being writable on execution), it gets deleted at the end of the run.

I believe you could change your script:

```
with open('/opt/saveOut.pkl','wb') as myFile:
    pickle.dump(myTable,myFile)
```

and then bind the local directory and get the output you're looking for:

```
sudo singularity exec -B ./:/opt /tmp/debian python3.5 /usr/src/test.py
```

This worked for me, anyway.